# Spoof USB vendor id / product id

Tags: usb, usb-storage, spoofing, product-id, vendor-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change USB vendor id / product id](https://superuser.com/questions/127494/change-usb-vendor-id-product-id)

I have a USB device that I need to spoof a copy of in windows. I was hoping you guys could point me to a program that would allow me to do such a task, or a walk through that would allow me to edit explorer.exe into thinking a similar device would be the spoofed device.

Comment: Could you perhaps give more details about the device you're trying to spoof, and why?