# Change or Hide Keyboard Type? / McAfee DLP

Tags: usb, keyboard, vendor-id

My keyboard is being blocked by McAfee DLP because it believes it's an Apple keyboard which is blocked for some unreason unknown. My keyboard has a physical switch on it which lets you switch from Apple Mode to PC Mode, however, it has always been in PC Mode, yet McAfee still thinks it an apple.

Is there any way to make a change to hide or change the keyboard type via the Registry or elsewhere, or some type of adapter to put between the USB ports to make it appear as a generic keyboard?

I know this might be pretty advanced and don't really expect for there to be a fix, but I thought I'd ask anyway since this place is loaded with incredibly smart people.

I viewed the keyboard in Device Manager, and it only show's as "HID keyboard Device" and in non of the properties does it show the name of the real manufacturer.

Thank you in advance if anyone think they know a workaround.

Thank you!

*This post and any comments are for informational purposes only to provide knowledge and educations to a particular subject matter so it can be documented for others to learn.

Comment: Are you the McAfee DLP admin user? If so then you can set an exclusion https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB86007

Comment: Hi, no, unfortunately, I'm don't have access and am not a McAfee DLP EndPoint Admin. They won't even give me a temporary bypass code. The problem is my keyboard has a physical switch on it. You can change it to PC Mode or Apple Mode. Even in PC Mode the keyboard shows up as an apple device so maybe something within the firmware or something always make it officially show as an Apple Device.

Comment: It's awesome, they even give you hot swappable keys so you can make it an Apple Keyboard or PC keyboard. I use Brown Gateron Low Profile Switches with a white Back light, so it's just amazing. So their primary reason for blocking my keyboard is they say it's an apple when it's not. It's the most comfortable and greatest keyboards I've ever used, and they don't make my hands or wrists hurt, even after 10.5 hours of work a day. + 60 hours of work as an IT engineer.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a device I can put between the USB connectors to make it a generic keyboard, or possibly something else. I'm an admin on the laptop, but I'd get in a lot of trouble trying to stop any security services. They auto restart from the GPO anyway. They have some super advanced settings where even an Admin on the computer can't change some of the settings or services.

Comment: I wish the Manufacture put more effort into the Device Manager information, but what can I do? Someone has to know how to do something!!! I'd be so grateful. My fingers and hands already hurt from using a piece of POC keyboard.

Comment: If anyone has any comments or any ideas to help the situation, please let me know. The security group will not grant me an except or whitelist my keyboard.

Comment: Use social engineering. Find out when the CEO's birthday is. Give her/him the same model of keyboard as a present and convince them it is the best keyboard ever made.

Comment: That won't work my friend, but fun to read. I am going to the top of the food chain to protest, however.

Comment: The problem is the Vendor ID, and Windows detecting it. It comes straight from the firmware which I can't modify. I contacted the manufacturer and they refuse to do anything. I found the reason why this is happening. My Keyboard Company decided not to get their own Vendor ID, and are using one from another Company. That's company is blocking and it's detected by Apple's Vendor ID of 05AC.

I found another post that dives into it, but doesn't give a definitive answer. If the post below had a solution I'd be saved.

https://superuser.com/questions/127494/change-usb-vendor-id-product-id