W10 Can't see whitelisted USB device after formatting
I have implemented several security policies that block USB devices based on their device ID's. However, when I format one of these devices, the policies prevent the system from recognizing it after formafting. The only way to regain access to the drive is by logging in as an administrator and temporarily disabling and re-enabling the policy. I would appreciate suggestions to resolve this issue.

What do you intend by "device ID"? Related threads are: https://superuser.com/questions/127494/change-usb-vendor-id-product-id   https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223572/secure-usb-unique-identifier  also note that anyone with some skills which knows your device's ID (from use on a different machine, for example) can replicate it

Such security policies are useless against someone that has physical access to your computer. All they get you is a headache.
